# Outline shader unity similar to the gizmo Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, outline

I wonder if I can get the same outline as in the Editor. 
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7viad.png)

I tried to use this script https://github.com/michaelcurtiss/UnityOutlineFX

And get [this as a result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLy8e.png)

Comment: Why minus? I do my best to make it as clear as possible

Comment: Sure theres one free in the asset store called quick outline I think

Comment: PS Please read [ask], [tour], [mcve] to understand how to improve your question

Comment: @BugFinder but it works even worse, see the pictures in the post

Comment: The github one is NOT the same as the one i suggested.

Comment: @BugFinder I wrote you, it works even worse, I had tried it before I asked here

Comment: Ok, but the picture in the post was for the outlinefx script - you didnt add one showing what the asset did.. but then said "See the pictures in the post" ..  Ive not had issues with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how you applied the scripts in the Github repo you linked to. It looks like the outline shader is only applied to the leaf material on the 3D model you posted, however I believe that this outline effect is meant to run as a post processing or replacement shader. I think that you're attaching a script or reference to the tree's leaves when you should be attaching it to the camera.

---

**Update**: I downloaded the repo and changed the "UnityOutlineFX.cs" script to work with multiple materials (the problem was that the script was originally only outlining the material in index 0). The fix is in the `RecreateCommandBuffer()` function, and I added the following code (note the for-loop through the different materials):

```cs
// render selected objects into a mask buffer, with different colors for visible vs occluded ones 
float id = 0f;
foreach (var collection in _objectRenderers)
{
    id += 0.25f;
    _commandBuffer.SetGlobalFloat("_ObjectId", id);

    foreach (var render in collection)
    {
        for(var i=0; i<render.sharedMaterials.Length; i++) {
            _commandBuffer.DrawRenderer(render, _outlineMaterial, i, 1);
            _commandBuffer.DrawRenderer(render, _outlineMaterial, i, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: The original problem (only one material was being outlined, with the blue and orange objects in this picture being part of one mesh)]

The original problem (only one material was being outlined, with the blue and orange objects in this picture being part of one mesh)

[image]
The outline working on a mesh (the orange and blue mesh) with three submeshes and two different materials.

Comment: The problem is only with the models having multiple materials.

Comment: I updated the post after changing the "UnityOutlineFX.cs" script to work with multiple materials.

Comment: That is a brilliant answer, but sorry I cannot upvote

Comment: No worries, glad I could help!

Comment: if anyone has found success using this shader in URP, please link. I have not been able so far